# Bitlocker + computer freezes after putting the correct password

Tags: windows-7, bitlocker

I use bitlocker on a 500 gb partiton in my hard drive. Windows 7 is also installed in the same drive. Before it was all fine but since this morning I haven't been able to start windows (it hangs at the welcome screen).

I switched on the computer then I enter the numerical bitlocker password but then it hangs at the welcome screen.

I tried accessing the bitlocker encrypted drive from other operating systems. The drive is shown as locked. When I tried to open it, it prompts for the password. When I enter the password the computer freezes. Please help me out. I have important data in that drive.

Comment: Is this a laptop drive or desktop drive? Is it external or internal?

Comment: Are we sure the storage device is in working condition?  Have you tried to access it from another Windows 7 machine?

Comment: Did you defrag your disk to make sure none of your Windows files were accidently in the part that was encrypted? My guess is that when Windows actually needs a few bits it can't get to them. - ALSO - Are those other OSes on the same disk, or are they live CDs / other computers? That's an important part.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered such situations and the drives that behaved like this were damaged. Get HDTune and perform a complete drive scan to make sure you have no bad sectors. Look at the S.M.A.R.T. attributes with the same tool to see if there are unallocated sectors.